# Facebook API. Attend to the event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to make possibility for attending to event in Facebook feed view in my app. Is it possible by POST-request of Graph API?

Comment: Why I need to code if I didn't find any documentation about such action?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/attending/

Comment: see? that is some important information you could already add to your question. you always need to add everything you have tried so far, right now this is way too broad for stackoverflow. also, you could try with a post request even if it´s not documented.

Comment: i suggest reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okey, I'll try to make post request :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IF it´s still possible, then by just doing a POST request to the attending endpoint. For example, with the JS SDK:

```
FB.api('/[event-id]/attending', 'POST', function(response){
    console.log(response)
});
```

Afaik it was possible earlier, and you would need the `rsvp_event` permission for this.

Edit: I just tried it in the API Explorer, it definitely works: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=[event-id]%2Fattending&version=v2.5 (of course you need to replace the event ID)